# closing the RadWindow is refreshing the parent page

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radwindow

im getting problem with radwindow..
when im clicking on radwindow and serching some content in the gridview, after that when im cliking on the close button that time the radwindow is closing, but the dropdownlist,values in the textbox of parentPage(aspx) is getting refreshing and nothing is working... why??  i have tried but im not getting..

Answer (score 0):

What is your code that causes the problem?

Most likely, you have an OnClientClose handler that invokes the postback/AJAX request that refreshses your dropdownlist.

Or, you have a JS error somewhere that you should fix.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
         function RadWindowClose() {
             debugger;
             var oWindow = null;
             if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
             else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
             oWindow.close();
         };
    </script><telerik:RadButton ID="rbClose" runat="server" Text="Close" Enabled="true" OnClick="rbClose_Click" 
                                        Visible="true">
                                    </telerik:RadButton> this above code i have writen for the close button

Comment: Please read my answer. This does not explain errors and refreshes on the parent page. Look in the parent page code too. Also, how to you call this script? Edit your answer with the relevant code that shows the problem and ping me in the comments so I can have a look

Comment: I dont have OnClientClose,Im having OnClick for closing the radwindow..
protected void rbClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Close Rad Window", "RadWindowClose()", true);
        }

Comment: IT is MY javaScript Code where im calling in the Close Buton
<script type="text/javascript">
         function RadWindowClose() {
             debugger;
             var oWindow = null;
             if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
             else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
             oWindow.close();
         };
    </script>